# Powershell: Copy-Item -Recurse -Force is not copying all sub files

Tags: powershell, recursion, copy, mode, copy-item

I have a one liner that is baked into a larger script for some high level forensics. It is just a simple copy-item command and writes the dest folder and its contents back to my server. The code works great, BUT even with the switches:

```
-Recurse -Force
```

It is not returning the file with an extension of .dat. As you can guess what I am trying to achieve, I need the .dat file for analysis. I am running this from a privileged account. My only thought was that it is a read/write conflict and the host file was currently utilizing it (or other sys file). What switch am I missing? The "mode" for the file that will not copy over is -a---. Not hidden, just not copying. Suggestions elsewhere have said to use xCopy/robocopy- if possible I do not want to call another dependancy- im already using powershell for the majority of the script, id prefer to stick with it....Any thoughts? Thanks in advance, this one has been tickling my brain for a little...

Comment: Does `Copy-Item C:\SOURCE\* C:\DESTINATION -Recurse -Force -Verbose` not do what you need?

Comment: Ahh okay...new intel, with the verbose switch, it states that it cannot be copied because it is being used- sort of what I thought...does anyone know of a way around this? like writing a read-only copy? I don't want to travel down process exploring if it is not needed- this is domain wide so thats a crazy envronmental change....

Comment: Uh, you can probably Shadow Copy for a dated version.  Maybe.  What OS?

Comment: Windows 7. Powershell < 3.0

Comment: Hopefully someone smarter comes by to help you.  This says it works on Windows 7 to get Shadow Copy info and data:  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Remote-Shadow-Volume-e5a72619 so that might help.

Comment: I'll give shadow copy a try tomorrow. Thanks Nate

Comment: the linked script seems to only get the shadow copy settings in place and not provide a way to harness shadow copy to copy files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to copy a file in use is to find the locking handle close it then retry the copy operation(`handle.exe`).

From your question it looks like you are trying to remotely copy user profiles which includes `ntuser.dat` and other files that would be needed to keep the profile working properly. Even if you did manage to find a way to unload the `dat` file(s), you would have to consider the impact that would have on the remote system.

Shadow copy is typically used by backup programs to copy files in use so your best bet would be to find the latest backup of each remote computer and then try to extract the needed files from the backed-up copies or maybe wait for the users to logoff and then try.

Comment: I'm guessing this is for system/application dependent files? For independent files you can usually grab a read only- even if they are locked. Guess I was hoping for a similar solution. Thanks for the feedback- seems there's no easier way- looking to go handle hunting.

Comment: if copy-item is reporting a failure about file being in-use then it may be some background process or service that hasnt let go of the file after use...i suspect the result would be the same even with xcopy or robocopy...anyway this can get you started on using `handle.exe`...but do note the author designed the script to be run locally and not from a remote system.. `http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/3744/friday-fun-find-file-locking-process-with-powershell/`

Comment: Yes the specific file in looking at is the IE > 8 webcachev**.dat. So IE locks this when a user is active- and for 3 min after log out. I can use a copy/invokeWMI (no psexec) to accomplish a .ps1 remotely. Thanks for the lead!